# Firefox 100% height div - scrollbar showing up

Tags: html, css, firefox

My Problem is described by this Code:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="extra"></div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.test {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
div.extra {
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    top:-50px;
}
```

​or in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XnKmW/3/

If you look at it, all things are in place - like they should be.

In Chrome and IE no scrollbar shows up. But in FF there is a scrollbar and you can scroll beyond that red div - this shouldn't be possible!

Making the any of the divs positon:absolute is not the answer I am searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get scroll because of this

```
div.extra {
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    top: -50px;
}
```

You are using `position: relative;` and than you are subtracting `-50px;` from `top`, instead take relative out and use `margin-top: -50px;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XnKmW/6/)

```
div.extra {
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Comment: @order66 you welcome and perhaps you should mark this answer as correct :)